# How to set "URL" for errors reported to New Relic from background tasks

Tags: java, error-reporting, newrelic

The **Events : Errors** tab in New Relic displays exceptions (date, time, message and stack trace) reported by my application using `NewRelic.noticeError(exception)`. For those reported from web transactions it shows the URL of the transaction which is perfect. But for background tasks reported using `@Trace` annotations it displays the name of the thread. This is meaningless because the threads have names like `pool-23-thread-9927`.

Can I assign a display name to each background task or pass one when reporting the error so that it shows in the **URL** column instead of the thread's name?

**Note:** I would prefer *not* to change the name of the thread if I can avoid it.

**Update**

Here's the overview of code. The transaction is contained in `PingJob` which catches and reports the exception.

```
public class PingJob implements Callable<PingStatus>
{
    @Trace(metricName = "ping", dispatcher = true)
    @Override
    public PingStatus call() {
        try {
            // calls that may throw exceptions
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // pass to utility method to log and/or report to New Relic
            ExceptionLogger.log(e, LOG);
        }
    }
}
```

I see the exceptions reported by `ExceptionLogger` on the New Relic site, but the URL column lists the name of the thread instead of the transaction, in this case `ping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what parameters you set in the `@Trace` annotation, you will see different values for the error URL recorded in the New Relic UI for an error in a background task.

Specifying the `metricName` and setting `dispatcher` to `true`, as in

```
@Trace(metricName = "YourErrorNameHere", dispatcher = true)
```

will set the displayed URL to *YourErrorNameHere*

Specifying no `metricName` but still setting `dispatcher` to `true`, as in

```
@Trace(dispatcher = true)
```

will set the displayed URL to your class name/method name, such as *com.example.task.BackgroundTask/run*

If you just use `@Trace` by itself without setting `dispatcher` to `true`, the thread name will be displayed.

We will be updating our documentation in the future to make this clearer.

Comment: It's working now. In the background task actually throwing exceptions, I mistakenly put the `@Trace` annotation on a method further down the call chain so that `noticeError` was called outside of the transaction.